# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in dataframe.iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop over a dataframe like the following:

```
for row, index in split[0].iterrows():
        kitname = row['kit_name'][0]
        print(kitname)
```

where `split` is a list of dataframes

```
split[0] :

  kit_name          kit_info         part_name part_number  
0  KIT0001  Standard FLC Kit  Standard FLC Kit           0   
1  KIT0001  Standard FLC Kit  Standard FLC Kit           0   
2  KIT0001  Standard FLC Kit  Standard FLC Kit           0
```

but the following error is coming:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using the same code in a different script and it's working fine there

Comment: try `print(row['kit_name"], row['kit_name"])` to find the problem. You need to know how to find a look for a problem by yourself, if not you'll take so much time to develop your thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you swap `index` and `row` variables, so `row` are integers so select `['kit_name']` failed:

```
for row, index in split[0].iterrows():
    kitname = row['kit_name'][0]
    print(kitname)
```

Need:

```
for index, row in split[0].iterrows():
    kitname = row['kit_name'][0]
    print(kitname)
```